# Powershell split-path fails with path in variable sourced from get-itemproperty

Tags: powershell

I would like to find the parent directory of a file using Powershell 2.0.

I find the location of the file from a registry key as follows:

```
(get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\CCUMessageConnectionServer").ImagePath

"O:\Program Files (x86)\CosmoCom\Server Components\Message Connection Server.exe"
```

I want to use `split-path` on this path, to obtain the parent directory. I try the below which fails:

```
PS C:> $a = (get-itemproperty `-path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\`CCUMessageConnectionServer").ImagePath

PS C:> split-path $a

Split-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"O' does not exist.
At line:1 char:11
+ split-path <<<<  $a
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("O:String) [Split-Path], `DriveNotFoundException`
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : `DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand`
```

If I manually assign the text returned by `get-itemproperty`, as below then split-path works

```
PS C:> $a = "O:\Program Files (x86)\CosmoCom\Server Components\Message Connection Server.exe"

PS C:> split-path $a
O:\Program Files (x86)\CosmoCom\Server Components

PS C:>
```

I have piped both `$a` and the `get-itemproperty` commands into `get-member` and both return identical members:

```
TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone()
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB)
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
CopyTo           Method                System.Void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex,...
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringCompari...
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string...
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator()
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()
GetType          Method                type GetType()
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode()
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf...
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), i...
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normaliz...
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startI...
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizat...
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char padding...
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, s...
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int...
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringCom...
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}
Length           Property              System.Int32 Length {get;}
```

Comment: Why not try to cast the registry value to string ? `$a = [string](get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\`CCUMessageConnectionServer").ImagePath`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but this now fails as below:PS C:> $a = [string](get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\CCUMessageConnectionServer").ImagePath
PS C:> $a
"O:\Program Files (x86)\CosmoCom\Server Components\Message Connection Server.exe"
PS C:> split-path $a
Split-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"O' does not exist.
At line:1 char:11
+ split-path <<<<  $a
    + CategoryInfo          : ("O:String) [Split-Path], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.NET` method [GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[io.path]::GetDirectoryName($a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it fails as below: 
PS C:> [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($a)
Exception calling "GetDirectoryName" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."
At line:1 char:28
+ [io.path]::GetDirectoryName <<<< ($a)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

PS C:> $a
"O:\Program Files (x86)\CosmoCom\Server Components\Message Connection Server.exe"